# Can't track applications network communication under same machine

Tags: wireshark, netmon

I have a network application environment of 7 applications communicating with eachother through UDP and TCP. All of them using either the machine's local network IP or 127.0.0.1 (localhost) to listen on ports or connecting to eachother.

All these applications are running on a single test machine.

I want to analyze precisely how each application communicate with the others so I tried Wireshark and Netmon. However both Wireshark and Netmon don't show me any of the packets sent or received by any of these applications.

What can I do to analyze this environment? Does Wireshark or Netmon able to analyze that? Is there a problem tracking packets using same source and destination IP?

Answer (score -1):

what interface did you select in Wireshark for capturing traffic?
For your case, I think you should select "Adapter for loopback traffic" in Wireshark.
It will capture loopback communication for your locally hosted application.

Comment: This should be posted as a comment. Until you have commenting rights , consider upvoting the question. Indefinite answers will be downvoted.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, this is noted